# Tumbling Window Trigger in Azure Data Factory

Tags: triggers, azure-data-factory

How can I parameterize the tumbling window trigger in ADF to run between a specific time(9Am-10AM) daily.
Is it possible to achieve it through the MyWindowStart and MyWindowEnd parameters?

Regards,
Sandeep

Answer (score 0):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/UlEpY.png

ADFv2-A schedule trigger like mentioned in attachment would do a similar thing

ADFv1-Add offset in pipeline and datasets related to the same pipeline

"scheduler": {
          "frequency": "Day",
          "interval": 1,
          "offset": "09:30:00"
        }